# Find all c# code files in directory recursively in Bash

Tags: regex, bash

I'm trying to find all `.cs` and `.xaml` files in Bash using regex `find . -name '(^\w+\.cs$)|(^\w+\.xaml$)'`

It works in c# but doesn't work in git bash shell. Which regex i can use to find all the needed files?

Comment: Could you please precise why you used `\w`? Did you mean to only allow any Unicode letters, digits and `_` (actually, in C#, `\w` matches even more connector punctuation and some diacritic symbols) or just any non-whitespace char?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew i meant upper or lower letters `[A-Za-z]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With GNU `find`, you may use

```
find . -regextype posix-extended -regex '.*/[a-zA-Z]+\.(cs|xaml)'
find . -regextype posix-extended -regex '.*/[[:alpha:]]+\.(cs|xaml)'
```

The pattern will match the whole path (note that `find` pattern must match the whole string) that matches

- `.*/` - any 0+ chars as many as possible up to the last `/`
- `[a-zA-Z]+` - 1+ upper- or lowercase letters (`[[:alpha:]]+` will match 1+ letters)
- `\.` - a dot
- `(cs|xaml)` - `cs` or `xaml` substring.

NOTE: To only match ASCII letters you should use `LC_ALL=C` before the `find` command:

```
LC_ALL=C find . -regextype posix-extended -regex '.*/[[:alpha:]]+\.(cs|xaml)'
```